# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', this is happening in socket

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io, cors

I am creating an application using socket.io and using ReactJs as frontend and NodeJs as backend. I have implement socket in the project to communicate between frontend and backend based on the users present at a time. Everything was working fine when I am executing it on local host, but after the completion of the project, I hosted both backend and frontend on netlify and in that I am getting cors policy error saying the below:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://google-docs-backend.netlify.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Oog1MmL' from origin 'https://google-docs-frontend.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
GET https://google-docs-backend.netlify.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Oog1WY0 net::ERR_FAILED 404 (Not Found)
```

I was expecting that the connection should establish of socket as it is working on localhost and both frontend and backend should communiacate properly.

I tried to pass a few headers like below but it did not worked:

```
const corsOptions ={
  origin: CLIENT_URL,     // "https://google-docs-frontend.netlify.app"
  credentials:true,
  optionSuccessStatus:200
}

const app = express();

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "https://google-docs-frontend.netlify.app"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  next();
});

const io = require("socket.io")(3001, {
  cors: {
    origin: CLIENT_URL,        // "https://google-docs-frontend.netlify.app"
    method: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});
```

Now below is the frontend code where I am calling the socket

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const s = io(SOCKET_URL);      // "https://google-docs-backend.netlify.app/"
    setSocket(s);
    return () => {
      s.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

I wanted to establish the connection of sockets from frontend to backend.

Comment: It looks like your client isn't connecting to the right port. At least in the code you shared it suggests that you have socket.io running on port 3001.

Comment: @Evert, can you tell me what should I add in the port instead of 3001?

Comment: Why are you configuring CORS three times in three different ways? It should be configured at most once.

Comment: @jub0bs I tried a few things but they are not working

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Earlier I was hosting my backend on netlify and it was causing the issue. Now I hosted my app on render.com and it is working completely fine.